# ¿Cómo mejorar la vista enviando data a ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#refresh-TE').on('click', function () {
      verModal(true);

      var $btn, respuesta = $('#form-te-refresh #resultado-te');
      var form = $('#form-te-refresh').serializeArray();

      // Limpieza del div que contiene las respuestas
      // devueltas por el back-end
      respuesta.removeAttr('class').empty();

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          url: '/usuarios/refresh',
          data: form,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache:    true,
          success: function (resultado) {
              if (resultado.success) {
                  setTimeout(refrescarPantalla, 2000);
              }

              $btn.button('reset');
          },
          beforeSend: function () {
              $btn = $('#refresh-TE').button('loading');
          }
      });

      return false;
  });
});

$('#delete-TE').on('click', function () {
  verModal(true);

  var $btn, respuesta = $('#form-te-delete #resultado-te');
  var form = $('#form-te-delete').serializeArray();

  // Limpieza del div que contiene las respuestas
  // devueltas por el back-end
  respuesta.removeAttr('class').empty();

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      url: '/usuarios/refresh',
      data: form,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache:    true,
      success: function (resultado) {
          if (resultado.success) {
              setTimeout(refrescarPantalla, 2000);
          }

          $btn.button('reset');
      },
      beforeSend: function () {
          $btn = $('#delete-TE').button('loading');
      }
  });

  return false;
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
    @if ((Auth::user()->hasRole("admin") || Auth::user()->hasRole("superadmin")) && $persona->getDiffInWeeks() > 1)
  <p>
    {!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form form-inline', 'name' => 'form-te-refresh', 'id' => 'form-te-refresh')) !!}
      {!! Form::hidden('cedula', $persona->cedula) !!}
      {!! Form::hidden('refresh', '1') !!}

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="refresh-TE" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-success btn-sm" autocomplete="off">
          <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i> Refrescar información
        </button>
      </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
  </p>
@endif

@if ((Auth::user()->hasRole("admin") || Auth::user()->hasRole("superadmin")))
  <p>
    {!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form form-inline', 'name' => 'form-te-delete', 'id' => 'form-te-delete')) !!}
      {!! Form::hidden('cedula', $persona->cedula) !!}
      {!! Form::hidden('refresh', '1') !!}

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="delete-TE" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-success btn-sm" autocomplete="off">
          <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>Eliminar registro
        </button>
      </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
  </p>
@endif
```

Estoy intentando crear dos botones, uno es para eliminar un registro que tenga más de un mes registrado y el otro puede ser de inmediato, ambos tienen que limpiarse el caché.

Lo que tengo actualmente funciona, la mejora seria eliminar un registro y limpiar y el cache de inmediato, pero me gustaría mejorar el código en `ajax` y la vista para que ambos funcionen como he mencionado anteriormente.

Comment: Perdón pero no estoy seguro de entender que es lo que quieres hacer. ¿Es solo refactoring o también tienes algún problema que no has resuelto?

Comment: realmente es refactoring, porque quiero mejorar el codigo ajax

Comment: Entonces quizás lo mejor sea mover la cuestión a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: si tengo esa pregunta en refactoring pero todavia no ha sido comentada

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161112/how-can-i-display-different-data-in-a-partial-view?noredirect=1#comment305389_161112

Comment: eso contiene un modal es la razon del porque quiero mejorar mi ajax que funcione para ambos botones y que el modal muestre informacion diferente dependiendo del caso que sea

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar los componentes de Blade o llamar subvistas para no repetir el código JS ni el HTML.

Teniendo en cuenta que tu código es un poco largo, te doy la idea para que lo implementes con subvistas:

**resources/views/partials/js-ajax.blade.php**

```
$('#{{ $action }}-TE').on('click', function () {
  verModal(true);

  // ...
});
```

**resources/views/modal.blade.php**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  @include('partials.js-ajax', ['action' => 'refresh'])

  @include('partials.js-ajax', ['action' => 'delete'])

});
```

Algo similar sería para el código HTML que tienes.

Más información en la documentación de Blade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade